# I want to get all USDT transfer events for the past ~2 hours on BSC mainnet. How can i do this?

Tags: blockchain, bsc

I want to get all USDT transfer events for the past ~2 hours on BSC mainnet.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The "right" way to do it is to have your own node running, that way you'll have access via the node API.
However this is not always possible for many reasons (private networks, you don't want to have a node running 24/7, etc).

So, I recommend that you investigate all the (reliable) BSC explorers, and investigate their APIs, through them you can surely access what you need since it does not seem very complex what you need, a regular API should have it.

I leave here the documentation of the *transactions* API of https://bscscan.com (very good BSC explorer)

https://docs.bscscan.com/api-endpoints/stats

Good day